# Acumatica Customization MS SQL MySql

Tags: acumatica

We have faced the following problem.
We were developing customization package under system on MySQL database.
All the database changes were added to customization from Customization Page.

Now when we are publishing this customization under system on MS SQL database we are getting errors associated with the differences between MySQL and MS SQL.
I have reviewed the xml's which Acumatica is generating for database changes and there are some differences, for example:

1. **timestamp** is set to have default value when xml is generated from MySQL database.
2. **Primary key** constraint has name **PRIMARY** when xml is generated from MySQL.

How can we solve this problem so that we have not to have two different packages, one for MySQL and the other for MS SQL?

Here is how Acumatica Generates Script for CS Attribute in case of MySql:

```
  <Sql TableName="csattribute" TableSchemaXml="#CDATA">
  <CDATA name="TableSchemaXml"><![CDATA[<table name="csattribute">
  <col name="CompanyID" type="Int" default="Zero" />
  <col name="AttributeID" type="NVarChar(30)" />
  <col name="Description" type="NVarChar(60)" />
  <col name="ControlType" type="Int" />
  <col name="EntryMask" type="VarChar(60)" nullable="true" />
  <col name="RegExp" type="NVarChar(60)" nullable="true" />
  <col name="List" type="NVarChar(MAX)" nullable="true" />
  <col name="IsInternal" type="Bit" nullable="true" />
  <col name="tstamp" type="Timestamp" default="CurrentDateTime" />
  <col name="CreatedByID" type="UniqueIdentifier" />
  <col name="CreatedByScreenID" type="Char(8)" />
  <col name="CreatedDateTime" type="DateTime" />
  <col name="LastModifiedByID" type="UniqueIdentifier" />
  <col name="LastModifiedByScreenID" type="Char(8)" />
  <col name="LastModifiedDateTime" type="DateTime" />
  <col name="NoteID" type="UniqueIdentifier" />
  <index name="CSAttribute_NoteID">
    <col name="NoteID" />
    <col name="CompanyID" />
  </index>
  <index name="PRIMARY" clustered="true" primary="true" unique="true">
    <col name="AttributeID" />
    <col name="CompanyID" />
  </index>
</table>]]></CDATA>
</Sql>
```

And the same table in case of MS SQL:

```
    <Sql TableName="csattribute" TableSchemaXml="#CDATA">
        <CDATA name="TableSchemaXml"><![CDATA[<table name="csattribute">
  <col name="CompanyID" type="Int" default="Zero" />
  <col name="AttributeID" type="NVarChar(30)" />
  <col name="Description" type="NVarChar(60)" />
  <col name="ControlType" type="Int" />
  <col name="EntryMask" type="VarChar(60)" nullable="true" />
  <col name="RegExp" type="NVarChar(60)" nullable="true" />
  <col name="List" type="NVarChar(MAX)" nullable="true" />
  <col name="IsInternal" type="Bit" nullable="true" />
  <col name="tstamp" type="Timestamp"/>
  <col name="CreatedByID" type="UniqueIdentifier" />
  <col name="CreatedByScreenID" type="Char(8)" />
  <col name="CreatedDateTime" type="DateTime" />
  <col name="LastModifiedByID" type="UniqueIdentifier" />
  <col name="LastModifiedByScreenID" type="Char(8)" />
  <col name="LastModifiedDateTime" type="DateTime" />
  <col name="NoteID" type="UniqueIdentifier" />
  <index name="CSAttribute_NoteID">
    <col name="NoteID" />
    <col name="CompanyID" />
  </index>
  <index name="CSAttribute_PK" clustered="true" primary="true" unique="true">
    <col name="CompanyID" />
    <col name="AttributeID" />
  </index>
</table>]]></CDATA>
    </Sql>
```

Comment: The package should be universal, however we build our package using MSSQL which will publish fine for MySQL. If you build your package on MS SQL do you get the same errors or no errors when running on MySQL? can you include the generated XML difference between the two in your question?

Comment: @Brendan In case of building package using MS SQL I am only getting errors for custom sql scripts(not create table) for Acumatica versions lower 6.1, because in that versions there is no way to tell Acumatica to run query under MySQL or not.

Comment: ah i see. I know there is in 2017R2 and it might work for 6.1 - i will post an answer

Comment: also, re-reading your post you are trying this in version 5.3? If you use the MS SQL build script, can you use it in MySQL? maybe the plan would be to use MS SQL as the base and deploy to My SQL That way. We have used our MS SQL package in My SQL in 5.3

Comment: @Brendan no, currently I need this for 6.0 and upper versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indicate if the script should run specifically for MySQL or MS SQL in a custom SQL script in your project if you use the following key words...

for a MySQL statement use the following:

```
--[mssql: Skip]
--[mysql: Native]
-- include your MySQL Code here...
```

for a MS SQL statement use the following:

```
--[mssql: Native]
--[mysql: Skip]
-- include your MS SQL Code here...
```

These sql script attributes are available in the help within an Acumatica site under:
**Customization Guide > Managing Items in a Project > Database Scripts > To Add a Custom SQL Script to a Project** ([Public help article](https://help.acumatica.com/Wiki/(W(2))/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=a59f0325-9639-437a-bc7a-f4f645f93f0e))

This information is based on 2017R2. You would have to test and confirm its use in 6.1.

Below is an example I currently use in 2017R2. Note the importance of needing to run the scripts in an order in 6.1 you might have to name the script something to make it run in a specific order (Ex: use "Upgrade..." to run last or "AUpgrade..." to run first). In 2017R2 you can set priority values which control the order of execution and even in the edit script window you have a "Specify Database Engine" button which will add the attributes for you.

[image]

Comment: I will check this

Comment: If I have done all correct --[mssql: Skip] is not working for 6.10 version. But anyway I think this answer is correct

Comment: Alternatively if you do not need to change column datatypes or something related to SQL Schema, you can write "scripts" direct in C# and use a CustomizationPlugin to perform data updates. This is what I typically use as its easier to maintain. This would be universal to any DBMS used. see https://help.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=3ef5784b-1602-4a04-b6b9-52b69c79fe91